# how to put a value in percentage into the watermark that will be over the value of the image

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have two images, a watermark and another that will receive the mark. I would like for example: to put a value in percentage into the watermark that will be over the value of the image

My code:

```
public void SetBodyWater(){
    this.gr = Graphics.FromImage(this.image);
        
    float w =  this.image.Width*this.percent/100;
    float h =  this.image.Height*this.percent/100;

    if(this.waterMark.Width>this.image.Width){
        w  =  w/this.waterMark.Width;
        w  = w*this.waterMark.Width;
        this.width = Convert.ToInt32(w);
    }else{
        this.width =this.waterMark.Width;
    }
    
    if(this.waterMark.Height>this.image.Height){
        h =  h/this.waterMark.Height;
        h = h*this.waterMark.Height;
        this.height = Convert.ToInt32(h);
    }else{
         this.height = this.waterMark.Height;
    }


    int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width / 2 - this.width / 2);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height / 2 - this.height / 2);
    
    Console.Write($"{this.width},{this.height}");

    this.gr.DrawImage(this.waterMark, x, y, this.width, this.height);

    this.GetFormat();
    this.image.Save($"{this.pathNew}/{Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), this.extensao.ToLower())}",
    this.format);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Very unclear but: `/100;` try `/100f;` !

Comment: I want the watermark to be a percentage value of the image

Comment: _a percentage value of the image_ and what is that supposed to mean??? Are you maybe talking about alpha (ie its transparency)? If so look up ColorMatrix and alpha..  Or do you want to show some characters or digits in the watermark? Use DrawString.

Comment: no i want the watermark to be proportionally on the image that will receive it

Comment: You mean the size? If so, use the DrawImage overload that takes two Rectangles!

Comment: I'm already using it I just want to know how I do the percentage calculation

Comment: _I'm already using it_ No, I can't see that.. - Also: What data type is `this.percent` ?

Comment: Best forget what you have and simply scale the graphics object: `g.ScaleTransform(percent/ 100f,percent / 100f);` - You may want/need code to center it..

Comment: percent is of type int. I used this code but it didn't work            `this.gr.ScaleTransform(this.percent/ 100f,this.percent / 100f);
            this.gr.DrawImage(this.waterMark, x, y)`

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description! - What happens? Nothing? Errors? (Which?) Crashes? Wrong results? (Which?)  - It works fine here!

Comment: I have a 349x47 watermark. its slightly out of the image...my image  200x200

Comment: So? We really can't help if you won't give us enough info. The code shows how to draw a scaled image. Does that part work or not?

Comment: So, the code doesn't give an error, it works, but the watermark is a little out of the image

Comment: If it is scaled down that's a start. To scale 349 down to 200 pixels you need around 57%  The best placement is another matter. If you draw it at (0,0) it should start at the top left corner..

Comment: My problem is that the watermark and the image can be any size. The user who is going to put it. Thank you for your commitment

Comment: So? You will have to calculate the % after the user has chosen the watermark then..: image.width / watermark.width (or heights, or both and then use the minimum)

Comment: The problem is to make this calculation work. my calculation is distorting the watermark

Comment: The scaling factors must be equal for both directions, of course. That's why I wrote :'width...height.. both and then use the minimum'

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
        public void SetBodyWater(){
        this.gr = Graphics.FromImage(this.image);

      if(this.waterMark.Height<this.image.Height && this.waterMark.Width<this.image.Width){
            this.width =  Convert.ToInt32(this.waterMark.Width*this.percent/100);
            this.height = Convert.ToInt32(this.waterMark.Height*this.percent/100);
        }else{
            // float w =  (float)this.image.Width*this.percent/100;
            // float h =  (float)this.image.Height*this.percent/100;

            float w = (float)this.image.Width/this.waterMark.Width;
            float h =  (float)this.image.Height/this.waterMark.Height;

            float maxW = Math.Min(w,h);
            float maxH = Math.Min(w,h);
            if(this.waterMark.Width>this.image.Width){
                maxW =(float) maxW*this.waterMark.Width;
                maxW = (float)maxW*this.percent/100; 
                this.width = Convert.ToInt32(maxW);

                // w  = (float) w/this.waterMark.Width;
                // w  =(float)  w*this.waterMark.Width;
                // this.width = Convert.ToInt32(w);
                
            }else{
                float hs =  (float)this.image.Height*this.percent/100;
                h = (float)  h/this.waterMark.Height;
                h = (float) h*this.waterMark.Height;
                this.height = Convert.ToInt32(h);

                float p =(float) this.height/this.waterMark.Height;
                this.width =  Convert.ToInt32(p*this.waterMark.Width);
            }
            
            if(this.waterMark.Height>this.image.Height){
                maxH =(float) maxH*this.waterMark.Height;
                maxH = (float)maxH*this.percent/100; 
                this.height = Convert.ToInt32(maxH);

                // h = (float)  h/this.waterMark.Height;
                // h = (float) h*this.waterMark.Height;
                // this.height = Convert.ToInt32(h);
            }else{
                float p =(float) this.width/this.waterMark.Width;
                this.height =  Convert.ToInt32(p*this.waterMark.Height);
            }
        }

        // int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width / 2 - this.waterMark.Width / 2);
        // int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height / 2 -  this.waterMark.Height / 2);

        int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width / 2 - this.width / 2);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height / 2 -  this.height / 2);
        
        Console.Write($"{this.width},{this.height}");


        //this.gr.ScaleTransform(sacle11,sacle12);
        this.gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        this.gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        this.gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        this.gr.DrawImage(this.waterMark, x, y,this.width,this.height);

        this.GetFormat();
        this.pathSucess = $"{this.pathNew}/{Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), this.extensao.ToLower())}";
        this.image.Save(this.pathSucess,this.format);
    }
```

my classes:

```
    using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
//using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Class
{
    public abstract class Img : IDisposable{
        private bool _disposed = false;
        protected Image image {get;set;}
        protected Image waterMark{get;set;}
        protected int width {get;set;}
        protected int height {get;set;}
        protected string path {get;set;}
        protected string pathWater{get;set;}
        protected string extensao {get;set;}
        protected string pathNew {get;set;}
        protected string pathSucess {get;set;}
        protected int percent {get;set;}
        protected int maxWidth {get;set;}
        protected int maxHeight {get;set;}
        protected ImageFormat format{get;set;}
        protected Graphics gr{get;set;}
        protected Color backColor{get;set;}
        protected Bitmap myBitmap {get;set;}
        protected MemoryStream ms{get;set;}
        public T GetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName)=> (T) obj.GetType()
                        .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .GetValue(obj);
        

        public void SetPrivateProperty<T>(object obj, string propertyName, T value)=>
            obj.GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(obj, value);
        

        public void GetFormat(){
            switch (this.extensao){
                case "GIF":
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                break;
                case "PNG":
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Png;
                break;
                case "JPEG":
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                break;
                default:

                break;
            }          
        }

        public void SetTransparent(){
            // Get the color of a background pixel.
            this.backColor = this.myBitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
            // Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
            this.myBitmap.MakeTransparent(this.backColor);
            // Draw the transparent bitmap to the screen.
            this.gr.DrawImage(this.myBitmap,0, 0,this.width,this.height);
        }

        public void GetImage(){
            
            this.ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(this.path));
            this.image = Image.FromStream(this.ms);
            this.extensao = this.image.RawFormat.ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        public void GetWaterMark(){
            this.ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(this.pathWater));
            this.waterMark = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    
        }

        public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
            if (_disposed){
                return;
            }

            if (disposing){
                // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
                this.gr?.Dispose();
                this.image?.Dispose();
                this.waterMark?.Dispose();
                this.ms?.Dispose();
                
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }


    }
}
```

Thumb class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Class{
    class Thumb:Class.Img{
          public void  ResizeMax(){
            this.GetImage();
            
            var ratioX = (double)this.maxWidth / this.image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)this.maxHeight / this.image.Height;
            var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            this.width = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width * ratio);
            this.height =Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height * ratio);
            
            this.SetBody();
        }

        
        public void SetBody(){
          // Create a Bitmap object 
            this.myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.width,this.height);

            this.gr = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
            this.gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            this.gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            this.gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
            this.gr.DrawImage(this.image, 0, 0,this.width,this.height);

            switch (this.extensao){
                case "GIF":
                    this.SetTransparent();
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                break;
                case "PNG":
                    this.SetTransparent();
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Png;
                break;
                case "JPEG":
                    this.format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                break;
                default:

                break;
            }
            
            this.pathSucess = $"{this.pathNew}/{Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), this.extensao.ToLower())}";
            this.myBitmap.Save(this.pathSucess,this.format);
        }


        public void ResizePercent(){
            // Task task = new Task(()=>this.GetImage());
            // task.Start();
            // task.Wait();
            this.GetImage();

            this.width = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width * this.percent / 100);
            this.height =Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height * this.percent / 100);
            this.SetBody();

        }

        
        public void SetBodyWater(){
            this.gr = Graphics.FromImage(this.image);

          if(this.waterMark.Height<this.image.Height && this.waterMark.Width<this.image.Width){
                this.width =  Convert.ToInt32(this.waterMark.Width*this.percent/100);
                this.height = Convert.ToInt32(this.waterMark.Height*this.percent/100);
            }else{
                // float w =  (float)this.image.Width*this.percent/100;
                // float h =  (float)this.image.Height*this.percent/100;

                float w = (float)this.image.Width/this.waterMark.Width;
                float h =  (float)this.image.Height/this.waterMark.Height;

                float maxW = Math.Min(w,h);
                float maxH = Math.Min(w,h);
                if(this.waterMark.Width>this.image.Width){
                    maxW =(float) maxW*this.waterMark.Width;
                    maxW = (float)maxW*this.percent/100; 
                    this.width = Convert.ToInt32(maxW);

                    // w  = (float) w/this.waterMark.Width;
                    // w  =(float)  w*this.waterMark.Width;
                    // this.width = Convert.ToInt32(w);
                    
                }else{
                    float hs =  (float)this.image.Height*this.percent/100;
                    h = (float)  h/this.waterMark.Height;
                    h = (float) h*this.waterMark.Height;
                    this.height = Convert.ToInt32(h);

                    float p =(float) this.height/this.waterMark.Height;
                    this.width =  Convert.ToInt32(p*this.waterMark.Width);
                }
                
                if(this.waterMark.Height>this.image.Height){
                    maxH =(float) maxH*this.waterMark.Height;
                    maxH = (float)maxH*this.percent/100; 
                    this.height = Convert.ToInt32(maxH);

                    // h = (float)  h/this.waterMark.Height;
                    // h = (float) h*this.waterMark.Height;
                    // this.height = Convert.ToInt32(h);
                }else{
                    float p =(float) this.width/this.waterMark.Width;
                    this.height =  Convert.ToInt32(p*this.waterMark.Height);
                }
            }

            // int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width / 2 - this.waterMark.Width / 2);
            // int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height / 2 -  this.waterMark.Height / 2);

            int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Width / 2 - this.width / 2);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.image.Height / 2 -  this.height / 2);
            
            Console.Write($"{this.width},{this.height}");
  

            //this.gr.ScaleTransform(sacle11,sacle12);
            this.gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            this.gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            this.gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            this.gr.DrawImage(this.waterMark, x, y,this.width,this.height);

            this.GetFormat();
            this.pathSucess = $"{this.pathNew}/{Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), this.extensao.ToLower())}";
            this.image.Save(this.pathSucess,this.format);
        }


        public void ResizePercentWater(){
            // Task task = new Task(()=>this.GetImage());
            // task.Start();
            // task.Wait();
            this.GetImage();
            this.GetWaterMark();

            this.SetBodyWater();

        }

    }
}
```

The percentage of the watermark will be relative to the image.